# Understanding Oauth2

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I am creating a REST inspired API for a Learning Management System. It will expose data such as users, classes, grades, courses etc. I have defined all the resources I want to expose, given them each an endpoint URL, and defined the JSON resource structures that are returned.

I now want to understand how to secure the API using Oauth2 (I don't want to use Oauth1). Am I correct in the assumption that my API will play the part of both the Authorization Server & the Resource Server? Also, what grant type / flow should I be researching?

A lot of the tutorials seem to focus on using Oauth2 to login using facebook credentials etc - but I just want to use it to secure my API and allow my users access to my API (either through a client, or directly). The access permissions for the API should follow the individual users access permissions that are already handled within our system.

Sorry for the scatter-gun questions - I just don't understand oauth2 enough to know where to direct my research. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and any pointers to simple tutorials for the correct use case would be great too.

FYI - The system is built on a LAMP stack using Drupal 6 (old, I know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your assumption is correct the authorization server and the resource server can be on the same server or in the same API.

So how the OAuth2 basically works you have some kind of client(Server, Browser) Authorization API will authorize with Access Token to use your resource API which is then sent in the the Authorization HTTP header on every resource request.

So what I success is that when the user logs in, you identify the user and generate the Access Token immediately to the client. Now you can put some data inside the Access Token e.g. userId, permissions etc. Now when the Access Token hits your resource endpoint you can identify the user and check the permissions. Also you can just make the Access Token dumb so it doesn't contain any data then when you validate it from Authorization API(on Access Token creation you have to store info about the user to Authorization DB), you can get the info you need on the response e.g. userId, permissions etc.

What grant type flow to use, this is basically up to question what kind of clients are using your Authorization API and how secure you want the Authorization to be. E.g. implicit grant is for browser based clients which can handle redirections and e.g. Client Credentials grant is for (server-to-server) communication.

Reference [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: It is assumption correct? For each new user a new client_id and secret are generated. This client_id is then granted permission on scopes.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can use existing providers like WSO2 API Manager for supporting your system. It is well documented and has many REST APIs for this.

Comment: Why would you outsource what's most desired, the user, to an external provider? Might aswell work for free.